# Sticky header that shrinks when scrolling down.. logo resizing

Tags: css, header, sticky, shrink

Everything works fine while shrinking except the logo. When you scroll it cuts the image. Im trying to make something like this http://www.zulijani.com
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE0xU.gif
Plz any ideas how to fix this:

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="masue">

    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html"><img src="home.png"> Početna</a></li>
            <li><a href="apartman1.html">Apartman 1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="apartman2.html">Apartman 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="galerija.html">Galerija</a></li>
            <li><a href="onama.html">O nama</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
        background:url(kvadrant1.png);
        opacity:0.7;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        margin:0px;
        text-align:left;
        font-family:"Myriad Pro";
        padding-top:0px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index:+1;
     }
.logo {
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        padding-top:0px;
        margin-left:150px;
        height:100%;
        background:url(logo.png);
      }
```

javascript

```
$('.header,.logo').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('.header,.logo').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('.header,.logo').data('size','small');
        $('.header,.logo').stop().animate({
            height:'80px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
  {
    if($('.header,.logo').data('size') == 'small')
      {
        $('.header,.logo').data('size','big');
        $('.header,.logo').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
      }  
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're not using the same width and height for the image when you scroll down.

Comment: I'll delete my answer for now, I'll update it and undelete it later. Give me some time :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4k5u5goL/ Hope I understood you right now :)

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Comment: Thank you Roman. That's exactly what I looked for :)
Steven no more tag of logos :p